# Passing an instance method to super with ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework

As I understand things, `this` is not available inside the constructor before `super( )` is called.

Still, when referring to instance methods, we need to prefix the method with `this`. So how is it possible to pass a instance method to `super( )`?

e.g. In the [Phaser framework](http://phaser.io), there is a [`Button`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.3/Phaser.Button.html) class. The constructor takes a callback for the click-event:

> **Constructor**
>   `new Button(game, x, y, key, callback, callbackContext, overFrame, outFrame, downFrame, upFrame)`
>
> **callback**  - The function to call when this Button is pressed.
>   **callbackContext** - The context in which the callback will be called (usually 'this').

I want my own button class, which I define like this:

```
class MyButton extends Phaser.Button {
    constructor(game) {
        super(game, game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'buttonImage');
    }

    clickHandler(button, pointer) {
       //handle the clicking
    }
}
```

So how will I pass the `clickHandler` to `super`?

`this.clickHandler` gives the error `[Build Error] 'this' is not allowed before super() while parsing file: ....` and passing just `clickHandler` gives me a runtime error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good use-case for [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which are bound lexically to `this`.

Here is a generic example of logging an instance-derived value by proxying the call to the instance method with an arrow function:

([Try it out on an ES6 REPL](https://tinyurl.com/pggvawf), or see it [compile in babel](https://tinyurl.com/phphkds).)

```
class A {
  constructor(method) {
    if(method) {
      method()
      return
    }
    this.callback()
  }

  message() {
    return "a"
  }

  callback() {
    console.log(this.message())
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super(() => this.callback())
  }

  message() { 
    return "b" 
  }

  callback() {
    console.log(this.message())
  }
}
```

As you can see, doing this allows us to avoid immediately referencing the `thisArg` of our new instance before our call to `super`. In your given example this is implemented like this:

```
class MyButton extends Phaser.Button {
    constructor(game) {
        super(
            game,
            game.world.centerX,
            game.world.centerY,
            'buttonImage',
            () => this.clickHandler()
        );
    }

    clickHandler(button, pointer) {
       //handle the clicking
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but that gave me a new runtime error from Phaser: `Uncaught Error: Phaser.Signal: listener is a required param of add() and should be a Function.`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work, I see `Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined` error when click on link Compile it in babel

Comment: @Tony It compiles fine for me - do you have the correct presets selected? [Here is the output](http://pastebin.com/USMyZDAz).

Comment: @sdgluck Sorry, I forget to mention about tiny change: just start to use it like this: `var o = new B();` and you will see the error

Comment: @Tony Ah! Looks like I was mistaken in my approach then. I will update with an alternative. Thanks for spotting!